# Google app engine custom DOMAIN not working

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I make some app on the google app engine.

But i have some problem. please see this picture.

[image]

I install my domain at app engine at custom domain.

but if i tried connect my web... (overdoc.org)

NOT FOUND DNS....

I talked my domain seller this problem. but they don't help me.

So.....

```
**How can i install my domain at app engine?**
```

Comment: Where is that screenshot from?

Comment: @DusanBajic first sorry for the late my answer. that page is Google app engine -> setting -> custom domain page.

Comment: Since you registered your domain with registrar other than Google, you should do this: https://cloud.google.com/dns/update-name-servers